# 8051 seven segment 1-9, and reset to 0

Tags: assembly, 8051

This is a university assignment, last part of 3. I cannot find any useful notes describing looping in the 8051 assembly language in the course resources, and the lecturer isn't replying to questions.  So I've started to cobble.

The brief says this:

[image]
[image]

What I've been strugglng with is 1st off, what does he mean by "convert"? There's nothing coded into those binary values 1-9 that can be algorithmically "converted" into a 7 segment equivalent. The only way I know to do this is to just WRITE those values and store them, then map between each. I've done that, just writing each value as a hex value and storing it in a register.

As it stands, I'm wondering 2 things:

Am I going in the wrong direction here, or is this brief asking me to do something that's impossible as I suspect?

If you run this program currently you'll see I'm using R0 as the "pointer." I can increment it IF not equal to 9, but I don't have a compare option. I need a way to say "WHEN R0 Equals 09H, jump back to the start of the sequence." I'm not seeing how to do that.

```
ORG 0000H
MOV 30H, #00
MOV 31H, #01
MOV 32H, #02
MOV 33H, #03
MOV 34H, #04
MOV 35H, #05
MOV 36H, #06
MOV 37H, #07
MOV 38H, #08
MOV 39H, #09
MOV 50H, #0C0H  ; this is just me storing the 
MOV 51H, #0F9H  ; seven segment mappings
MOV 52H, #0A4H  ; for binary digits 1-9. 
MOV 53H, #0B0H
MOV 54H, #099H
MOV 55H, #092H
MOV 56H, #082H
MOV 57H, #0F8H
MOV 58H, #080H
MOV 59H, #090H


BACK: MOV A, 58H  ; flash the contents of 68h, (number 8 for now)
      MOV P1, A  ;
      ACALL DELAY
      MOV A, #0FFH
      MOV P1, A
ACALL DELAY
SJMP BACK

DELAY: MOV R6, #0FFH
AGAIN: MOV R7, #0FFH
HERE: DJNZ R7, HERE
      DJNZ R6, AGAIN
      CJNE R0, #09H, NEXT_NUMBER
       R0, 
      RET     
      NEXT_NUMBER:
      INC R0  
      RET    
      END
```

Comment: Use another register as a counter and use DJNZ to loop. You don't need to compare the pointers directly.

Comment: OP, you posted *Also, shouts out to the dude who meticulously corrected my message to a writing style he preferred. Profoundly entertaining to review on an un-answered question.* Click on 'Edited n hours ago" and use the edit rollback to get it back to your earlier version, if you prefer. Your question should reflect what you are saying more than give way to the grammatical corrections of someone else. Mind you, you could always have written in decent-quality English in the first place. Look at some of the high-scored questions on this site for examples of what's expected.

Comment: No thanks, as I said, he corrected it. 
"Your question should reflect what you are saying more than give way to the grammatical corrections of someone else"

To the extent you're saying "don't grammar make mistakes" here... I agree. It shouldn't. I don't think the ones I made made the question inintelligable, but thanks for your feedback, and rest assured I'm communicating that feeling while also acknowledging the question is improved, and in what ways. ;)

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm saying, which was that correcting other people's answers isn't good if it also removes their self-expression. But, anyway, you get it :-) The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Meanwhile: have you searched the internet and used the tons of 8051 example programs to finish your own homework yet?

Comment: To get a sense of the human element, imagine a person with 30 flowcharts, the 8051 instruction set, a folder of search results, and 4 days 9 to 9 on this specific problem... 
I'm embarassed because I know you're thinking "this guy cannot be that stupid." but I will take stupid over lazy anyday. I assure you I don't come here as a 1st, 2nd, or 10th resort. 

The poor english, and the kinda-snotty sarcastic thank you for the edits all come from that place. I'm sorry, and I appreciate the rebuke, well deserved on my part.

Comment: @EmptyAtoms, please note that it's not a discussion forum but a Q&A site, so extended chat in lengthy comments isn't its purpose. There's a rather personal note in your long replies that's not what anyone's here for. You have everything you need, I'll leave you to it and wish you well.

Answer (score 0):

'Convert' would mean producing a 7-segment pattern for each BCD digit you have.

There's no computational function to go from an entire BCD digit to an entire 7-segment pattern. In an electronic circuit, a big pile of AND-OR functions on individual bits can produce it. In software, use a look-up table like you have and index into it using the digit value.

So, for look-up table at address 'Table' and for digit 'digit', that part of your program is:

```
mov   A,digit
mov   #Table
movc  A,@DPTR+A
```

Comment: I'm not understanding your answer. I think you're suggesting how to do the next part after the bit I'm struggling with. 

To clarify, what I need right now is a pointer that counts up from 0-9, then resets at zero and goes again. 

I know it's got to be very simple, but even with what Spehro offered... I don't know how to use DJNZ (or anything else) to increment, and jump WHEN 9 (to a subroutine that decrements 9 back down). 

Also, shouts out to the dude who meticulously corrected my message to a writing style he preferred. Profoundly entertaining to review on an un-answered question.

Comment: @EmptyAtoms, you asked two questions in one: what is convert, how do you do the pointers. I've answered the first. The second is wanting me to do your homework for you, what obviously ain't happening. The site's not a free homework-answering service, nor for free personal tutorial. It's to help you take the next step on your own. You will find plenty of 8051 assembler tutorials on the internet only a quick search away.

Comment: My aim is to produce a number in the counter which loops in the way I describe. These are very distinct questions in terms of their Google-ability... one is syntax, the other is a question about program flow/logic.

"I don't know how to use DJNZ (or anything else) to increment, and jump WHEN 9 (to a subroutine that decrements 9 back down)."

I did not ask "how do I do pointers", and on the contrary, my view is that you're doing my homework for me there, instead of answering my question. I also haven't conscripted you personally for anything, if you believe I'm here in bad faith, leave?

Answer (score 0):

Jump commands are used for looping but there are many ways to do this. If you want to see how it's done write a for loop (or any kind of loop) in C and then look at the assembler code.

Comment: Okay. So like write 

for (i == 0 ; i<9 ; i++){
output (i)
}

And look at the assembly code for that? I'd wonder if that produces instructions that the 8051 doesn't 
have? I'm noticing there are options like CMP that'd get me out of this but I can't do that within EdSim. 

I will certainly do this though I've found this which I'll study.
Thank you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840321/how-can-i-see-the-assembly-code-for-a-c-program

Comment: Compile it for an 8051...

Comment: I've never written in C or compiled for, or flashed anything onto a real 8051, definitely worth learning in the long term. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I can increment it IF not equal to 9, but I don't have a compare option. I need a way to say "WHEN R0 Equals 09H, jump back to the start of the sequence." I'm not seeing how to do that.

Got it! Thank you everybody.

What I needed to do was think of the line below the
compare and jump if not equal R0, #09h, as an implied "else" condition.
I typed the reset instruction in there and it only triggers when R0 = 9

```
ORG 00H
MOV 58H, #080H ; just using this one seven segment value for legibility
;lookup tables go here

BACK: MOV A, 58H  ; flash the contents of 58h, (number 8)
      MOV P1, A  ; A will eventually be pointer (@R0)
      ACALL DELAY
SJMP BACK

DELAY: MOV R6, #0FFH
AGAIN: MOV R7, #0FFH
HERE: DJNZ R7, HERE
      DJNZ R6, AGAIN
      CJNE R0, #09H, NEXT_NUMBER; if r0<9, skip below line to NEXT_NUMBER
      MOV R0, #00H ; if we're here, r0 IS now 9, make it 0 again.
      RET
      NEXT_NUMBER:
      INC R0
      RET
      END
```